# System.Dbtype for a DB2 Timestamp value

Tags: c#, .net, db2

I have an internal library which has an API to call DB2 Stored Procs.
As part of the parameter binding, the syntax is:

```
SPParameter(string paramName, DbType dbType, object paramValue)
```

One of the input params of the Stored Proc is of the type Timestamp. 
I am unable to find a `System.DbType` enum which will work in this case. The possible enums and the error i get are:

1. `Date: Error in DB Write: ERROR [42884] [IBM][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0440N`
2. `DateTime: Error in DB Write: ERROR [42884] [IBM][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0440N`
3. `DateTime2: Error in DB Write: No mapping exists from DbType DateTime2 to a known DB2Type.`
4. `Time: Error in DB Write: ERROR [42884] [IBM][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0440N`

Any suggestions on which enum to use?any other approach?

Comment: While maybe not the best idea, worth a shot.  Try using string or int types, for their respective Alphanumeric, Signed Numeric or Packed Numeric DB2 types.  I've had success in the past this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue was in the order of Params i was entering. Even though I name the Params, it is required for them to be in order in which they are defined in the Stored Proc. Correcting the order solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

SQL0440N means that the procedure you're trying to call does not exists, so I suspect three times out of four the error is not in the data type you are using.